# pst-optexp: draw 4f correlator

Tags: pstricks, pst-optexp

I recently discovered `pst-optexp` and am trying to draw my optical setup for an experiment on it before my deadline. I was looking through the [docs](http://ftp.univie.ac.at/packages/tex/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-optexp/pst-optexp.pdf) and it is an amazing package but there is so much in it that I'm finding it very hard to actually draw what I want, and I was hoping someone could help me. I have spent hours fiddling with it trying to get it to work but I haven't got anything useful and it is getting quite frustrating. My setup is a [4f correlator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_correlator). I have tried to draw something similar to Ex. 11.5 (page 129 of the [docs](http://ftp.univie.ac.at/packages/tex/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-optexp/pst-optexp.pdf)) but I can't position the lens correctly and get the beams to focus the way I want (it's not worth posting my attempt because I don't think it's at all usable).

A crude sketch of my experimental setup is shown below. As you can see there are a lot of lenses and foci to get right.

[image: setup sketch]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know, that the workflow maybe isn't very intuitive and you'll need to workout how you can best work.

Here is a document which reproduces your experimental setup:

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt, pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-optexp}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(14,3.5)
   \psset[optexp]{labeloffset=0.8, labelangle=180}
    \pnodes(2,1.5){Start}(12,1.5){End}
    \begin{optexp}
        \optbox[innerlabel, position=start](Start)(End){Laser}
        \lens[lens=-1.5 -1.5 1 0.1, abspos=1, n=2](Start)(End){$D_1$}
        \lens[lens=3 3 1.3, abspos=2.5, n=1.7](Start)(End){$C_2$}
        \pinhole[abspos=4, phwidth=0.05](Start)(End){$A_3$}
        \lens[lens=3 3 1.3, abspos=5.5, n=1.85](Start)(End){$C_4$}
        \lens[lens=3 3 1.3, abspos=8.5, n=1.95](Start)(End){$C_5$}
        \optbox[innerlabel, position=end](Start)(End){CCD}
        \addtopsstyle{Beam}{fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=green!50!white}
        \drawwidebeam[beamwidth=0.2]{1-4}
        \drawwidebeam[beamwidth=0.1, beamdiv=20]{4-7}
    \end{optexp}
    \optplate[compname=fourier, 
              abspos=7, plateheight=1.5, 
              labelalign=b,
              linewidth=0.5\pslinewidth, linestyle=dashed](Start)(End)%
       {\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}Fourier\\plane\end{tabular}}
    \psset{arrows=|*-|*}
    \pcline([offset=-1]\oenodeCenter{1})([offset=-1]\oenodeCenter{2})
    \ncput*{$f_2$}
    \pcline([offset=-1]\oenodeCenter{3})([offset=-1]\oenodeCenter{4})
    \ncput*{$f_4$}
    \pcline([offset=-1]\oenodeCenter{4})([offset=-1]\oenodeCenter{5})
    \ncput*{$f_4$}
    \pcline([offset=-1]\oenodeCenter{5})([offset=-1]\oenodeCenter{fourier})
    \ncput*{$f_4$}
    \pcline([offset=-1]\oenodeCenter{fourier})([offset=-1]\oenodeCenter{6})
    \ncput*{$f_5$}
    \pcline([offset=-1]\oenodeCenter{6})([offset=-1]\oenodeIn{7})
    \ncput*{$f_5$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

In this case my workflow was as follows:

1. Define start and end point.
2. Position all components from left to right using an absolute position (`abspos`).
3. Get the shape of all lenses like you want them to appear.
4. Start with a wide beam without divergence.
5. Adapt the refractive index `n` for every lens to fit your required beam path.

Yes, point 5 isn't how a real optical setup is choosen, but you want to draw a sketch which doesn't allow you to use the 'real' lens radii and focal distances.

I wrapped all components and beams inside an `optexp` environment, so that the beam is drawn below the components. Only the `fourier` component, which indicates the Fourier plane, is drawn afterwards because it must be over the beam.

[image]

Comment: That's pretty much exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much!